# Python virtualenv activation working but interpreter doesn't

Tags: python, virtualenv

I've just setup a new environment for my project and uploaded a python repository including `bin`, `lib` and project folder. I'm pretty sure I did same previously and it worked without problem. Now when doing the same on an AWS environment I get the error 
`-bash: /projects/scrapy/bin/python2.7: cannot execute binary file`. However when doing `source /projects/scrapy/bin/activate` it successfully activates the environment.

From what I understand, python should be able to execute without any issue no matter the environment ?

Any help or pointing to the right direction would be much appreciated!

Comment: Locally I use a Mac. Everything always worked perfectly until uploading the folder to the AWS virtual machine. isn't python working on a standalone environment ?

Comment: *python should be able to execute without any issue no matter the environment ?* No, the Python binary is tied to your specific OS and computer architecture.

Comment: A Python binary compiled to run on Macos will *not* work on Linux. Create a new virtualenv with a Python binary compiled for Linux, and install the same packages there. Use `pipenv` or a requirements.txt file to transfer the dependencies from Mac to Linux.

Comment: @MartijnPieters so actually the successful activation doesn't mean that it is working, right ?

Comment: nope, all it means is that you copied the `activate` shell script to another environment that also has a working shell interpreter that supports setting the `PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> python should be able to execute without any issue no matter the environment ?

No, the Python binary is tied to your specific OS and computer architecture. Python *source code* can usually be run on different machines (provided you didn't use OS-specific features), but that's only made possible by compiling a Python interpreter for the specific target environment *first*.

In other words, a Python binary compiled to run on macOS will *not* work on Linux.

All that `source bin/activate` achieves is that it configures your terminal setting to use the `bin` directory as the first directory on the `PATH` search path. This doesn't make `bin/python` work in another environment, it just means that both environments have a working shell interpreter that can run that script.

Create a new virtualenv with a Python binary compiled for Linux, and install the same packages there. Use [Pipenv](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/) or [a requirements.txt file](https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/1.1/requirements.html) to transfer the dependencies from Mac to Linux.

For example, using Pipenv you'd copy over the `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` files to the other computer, then run `pipenv install` in the directory there and re-create the virtualenv and dependencies from those files.

I recommend you read up on Python development best practices in the [*The Hitchhiker’s Guide to Python*](https://docs.python-guide.org/); this includes such topics on how to manage an environment for a project.